# Deleting Duplicates From An Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a code where I load up a text file and save it as an array. The array contains a list of numbers with some of the numbers being duplicated. In my code I first loop through the array and replace all duplicated numbers with a -1. Then I plan on deleting all the -1 values from my array. The remaining array values (non duplicates) are then copied on to a new array to be outputted.

However I keep getting an error when I attempt to delete the -1 values from my array (see code below). I don't know why this is happening so if anyone knows anything please let me know!

**P.S. This is school project so I can only use loops and if statements, not things like LINQ or foreach, etc.**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Global Variable
    int[] Original;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Exit Application
    private void mnuExit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    //Load File
    private void mnuLoad_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code to Load the Numbers From a File
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();

        //Open the File Dialog and Check If A File Was Selected
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Open File to Read
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fd.OpenFile());
            int Records = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

            //Assign Array Sizes
            Original = new int[Records];

            //Go Through Text File              
            for (int i = 0; i < Records; i++)
            {
                Original[i] = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Store Original Array
        string Output = "Original \n";

        //Output Original Array
        for (int i = 0; i < Original.Length; i++)
        {
            Output = Output + Original[i] + "\n";
        }

        //Create TempArray
        int[] TempArray = new int[Original.Length];

        //Set TempArray Equal to Original Array
        for (int i = 0; i < Original.Length; i++)
        {
            TempArray[i] = Original[i];
        }

        //Duplicate Number Counter
        int Counter = 0;

        //Loop Through Entire Array
        for (int i = 0; i < TempArray.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < TempArray.Length; j++)
            {
                //Replace Duplicate Values With '-1'
                if (TempArray[i] == TempArray[j])
                {
                    TempArray[j] = -1;
                    Counter++;
                }
            }

        }

        //Set Size of Original Array
        Original = new int[Original.Length - Counter];

        //Remove -1 Values

        //Index Counter
        int Index = 0;
//error starts
        for (int i = 0; i < TempArray.Length; i++)
        {

            if (TempArray[i] != -1)
            {
                 Original[Index] = TempArray[i];
                Index++;
            }
        }
//error ends
        //Final Output -- The New Array
        Output = Output + "Original Without Duplicates\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < Original.Length; i++)
        {
            Output = Output + Original[i] + "\n";
        }
        lblOutput.Text = Output;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `string` for the `Output`.

Comment: The code where you have marked the error to start and end is not correct. It's root is at a completely different place.

Comment: Can you at least use `List<T>`?

Comment: As mentioned by @displayName below, make all the duplicates into -1. then take the count of duplicate , create original array and assign the value.otherwise for eg:- i=0 and j=4 , you got a duplicate and  change to -1 . then i=4, value will be -1 and it will try to replace again if any duplicate got in J loop with -1.so counter  will calculate wrongly.i hope you got my point

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do in this case would be

```
Original = new int[Original.Length - (Counter-1)];
```

and yes you need to change the code to assign the values to Original instead of TempArray.

```
//error starts
for (int i = 0; i < TempArray.Length; i++)
{

    if (TempArray[i] != -1)
    {
        Original[Index] = TempArray[i];
        Index++;
    }
}
//error ends
```

Comment: it still keeps showing an error in the same spot! Any idea? An IndexOutOfRangeException to be exact.

Comment: @CoolCat: Because when you are doing `Original = new int[Original.Length - Counter];`, your `Counter` is wrongly calculated. It is more than the actual number of duplicates. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the line `TempArray[i] = Original[Index];` to `Original[Index] = TempArray[i];`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have three `3`'s in your array. In the outer loop when you iterate and come across a `3`, you set the other two `3`'s to `-1`. Now you come across the first `-1` which earlier was a `3` and you have already set the last `3` to `-1`. Now you search for duplicates and wrongly calculate your number of duplicates in the Duplicate Number Counter (called `Counter`) because for you `-1` is a duplicate of `-1`.

So, what you can do is this:

First only set all duplicates to `-1` and then count the number of `-1`'s by looping through the array again. This way you will set correctly the size of non-duplicated array elements.

To set all dups to `-1`:

```
for (int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < Original.Length; outerIndex++)
{
    var currentElement = Original[outerIndex];
    for (int innerIndex = outerIndex + 1; innerIndex < Original.Length; innerIndex++)
    {
        if (Original[innerIndex] == currentElement) Original[innerIndex] = -1;
    }
}
```

To get the count of non-repeating elements now:

```
var counter = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < Original.Length; index++)
{
    if (Original[index] != -1) counter++;
}
```

Creating non-duplicated elements' array:

```
var newArrayIndex = 0;
var newArray = new int[Original.Length - counter]; //Calculated counter above
for(int i = 0; i < Original.Length; i++)
{
    if (Original[i] != -1) newArray[newArrayIndex++] = Original[i];
}
//Finally, not good programming practice, but 
//you can set Original to this newArray if you like...
Original = newArray;
```